# enabling LM hash in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hashing, ntlm

Is there any way to enable/convert an NTLM hash for a user account on Windows 7 to a LM hash? I know it's not secure, but I am trying to test something. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NT hashes *are* NTLM hashes.

If you meant LM hashes, you can enable them via Group Policy (`secpol.msc`), but the changes will only apply after setting a new password – you cannot convert an existing hash to a weaker one. (This should be somewhat obvious, since the hashing would be entirely pointless if that was possible.)

Comment: Where would I go in the Group Policy?

Comment: Under *Local Policies → Security*, set "Network security: Do not store LAN Manager hash" to "Disabled". Optionally, adjust "Network security: LAN Manager authentication level" to accept and/or send LM in addition to NTLM. (Note that this is very insecure and must be reverted after tests.)